# Get Facebook newsfeed or notification feeds

Tags: facebook, feeds

How can I get a URL to a Facebook Newsfeed, and if possible, notifications feed?

There were methods to get Facebook Newsfeed to your application, but recently they haven't been working. Or maybe I'm using them wrong.

I used Rainmeter with some awesome widgets and several of them need us to input a URL of the newsfeed, but I can't figure out how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rainmeter and those other apps frequently expect an RSS feed for your account's notifications (for example when someone likes a comment of yours). Facebook does not provide your "News Feed" (friends' posts) via RSS, but only through their API.

The feed for your account's notifications can be found at https://www.facebook.com/notifications and copy the URL provided in the "RSS" link.

Comment: I'll try and provide you feedback asap. Thanks :)

Comment: Shinigamae, did that work for you? :)

Comment: I've not been home yet to try it. But by seeing the link format, I think it will work.

Comment: it works fine =) thanks. Sr for late response.

Answer (score 1):

[facebook-atom.appspot.com](https://facebook-atom.appspot.com/) can convert your Facebook news feed to an Atom feed that you can read in a feed reader.